# Trying to load a library in Python

Tags: python, libraries

I have Anaconda 32-bit Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10. 
The library is written in C++ and so I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (15.8) loaded too.

Problem I'm having is I get this error after running 'python setup.py install' whose output is in the attached file.

(C:\Users\david.callahan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda32bit) C:\Users\david.callahan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda32bit\Lib\site-packages\vnpy\python>python   Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 13:20:13) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from vnpy import * Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\david.callahan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda32bit\Lib\site-packages\vnpy\python\vnpy\libvncxx.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) File "C:\Users\david.callahan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda32bit\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import File "", line 983, in _find_and_load File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vnpy._libvncxx'

Not sure why it's not finding that library.

Comment: This `vnpy._libvncxx` smells like a extension, or native code, a `.dll`. I had problems where the extensions depends on another binary libraries that were not present in the system and the python throws a Module not found error, I would check if there is a `_libvncxx.dll` to start

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve this?